# How to use multiselect() without removing existing values and add new values based on another selection

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm with an e-learning project and working on the section of massive matriculation. I use a search box to look for students´ name, and add those values to a list. The problem appears when I try to look for other students' name and add those values to the existing list. This part reloads and all the previous values disappear. How can I display the result of new values and add them to the chosen list without removing the old one.

Code to display list (detail.php)

```
                <p>
                    <label>&nbsp;<?php echo $string['LBL_PROGRAM_NAME']; ?>: </label>
                    <input type="text" id="program_name" name="program_name"  class="tam1" maxlength="200"  value="<?php echo $program_name; ?>" />
                </p>
                <br class="clear"/>
                <center>
                    <input type="button" class="btn" name="buscar_programs" value="<?php echo $string['LBL_SEARCH_PROGRAMS']; ?>" onclick="javascript:loadPrograms();"/>
                </center>                       
                <p>
                    <label><b><?php echo $string['LBL_PROGRAMS_SELECT']; ?>: <span class="rojo">*</span></b></label>
                    <span id="area_programs">
                    <select id="programs" class="multiselect" multiple="multiple" name="programs[]">
                    </select>
                    </span>
                </p>
```

Function loadPrograms() (detail.php):

```
function loadPrograms(){
     $.ajax({  
          url: ruta_fichero_ajax+"loadProgramsItinerario.php?a1="+$('#program_name').val()+"&a2="+$('#center_id').val(),  
          dataType: 'json',  
          async: false,  
          success: function(datos){

                var strHTML = '<select id="programs" name="programs[]" class="multiselect" multiple="multiple">';
                if (datos.length>0){
                    $.each(datos, function(index, dato) {
                        strHTML += '<option value="' + dato.id + '">' + dato.name + '</option>';
                    });
                }                       
                strHTML += '</select>'; 
                document.getElementById("area_programs").innerHTML =  strHTML;

                $("#programs").multiselect();

           }  
        });     
}
```

I'm a junior and still have many things to learn with Javascript. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

To append new values to the options list, you can use below code(with jQuery cause you seem to be using jQuery)

```
$("#programs").append(new Option('TEXT', 'VALUE'));
```

Or using vanilla JS

```
selectElement = document.getElementById('programs');
selectElement.options[selectElement.options.length] = new Option('TEXT', 'VALUE');
```

Alternatively you can check [this](https://www.electrictoolbox.com/javascript-add-options-html-select/) or [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_select_add.asp) for detailed explanation.